# Python: Assign an object's variable from a function (OpenERP)

Tags: python, odoo

I'm working on a OpenERP environment, but maybe my issue can be answered from a pure python perspective. What I'm trying to do is define a class whose "_columns" variable can be set from a function that returns the respective dictionary. So basically:

```
class repos_report(osv.osv):
    _name = "repos.report"
    _description = "Reposition"
    _auto = False

    def _get_dyna_cols(self):
        ret = {}
        cr = self.cr
        cr.execute('Select ... From ...')
        pass           #<- Fill dictionary
        return ret

    _columns = _get_dyna_cols()

    def init(self, cr):
        pass    #Other stuff here too, but I need to set my _columns before as per openerp 

repos_report()
```

I have tried many ways, but these code reflects my basic need. When I execute my module for installation I get the following error.

```
TypeError: _get_dyna_cols() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

When defining the the `_get_dyna_cols` function I'm required to have `self` as first parameter (even before executing). Also, I need a reference to openerp's 'cr' cursor in order to query data to fill my _columns dictionary. So, how can I call this function so that it can be assigned to `_columns`? What parameter could I pass to this function?

From an OpenERP perspective, I guess I made my need quite clear. So any other approach suggested is also welcome.

Comment: Why don't you put the `_columns =` line inside of `__init__`?

Comment: No. Most likely he wants it as  a property - long answer bellow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From an OpenERP perspective, the right solution depends on what you're actually trying to do, and that's not quite clear from your description.
Usually the `_columns` definition of a model must be static, since it will be introspected by the ORM and (among other things) will result in the creation of corresponding database columns. You could set the `_columns` in the `__init__` method (not `init`<sup>1</sup>) of your model, but that would not make much sense because the result must not change over time, (and it will only get called once when the model registry is initialized anyway).

Now there are a few exceptions to the "static columns" rules:

### Function Fields

When you simply want to dynamically handle read/write operations on a virtual column, you can simply use a column of the [`fields.function`](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.1/developer/03_modules_2.html#functional-fields) type. It needs to emulate one of the other field types, but can do anything it wants with the data dynamically. Typical examples will store the data in other (real) columns after some pre-processing. There are hundreds of example in the official OpenERP modules.

### Dynamic columns set

When you are developing a wizard model (a subclass of `TransientModel`, formerly `osv_memory`), you don't usually care about the database storage, and simply want to obtain some input from the user and take corresponding actions.
It is not uncommon in that case to need a completely dynamic set of columns, where the number and types of the columns may change every time the model is used. This can be achieved by overriding a few key API methods to simulate dynamic columns`:

- [`fields_view_get`](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.1/developer/03_modules_2.html#openerp.osv.orm.BaseModel.fields_view_get) is the API method that is called by the clients to obtain the definition of a view (form/tree/...) for the model.
- [`fields_get`](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.1/developer/03_modules_2.html#openerp.osv.orm.BaseModel.fields_get) is included in the result of `fields_view_get` but may be called separately, and returns a `dict` with the columns definition of the model.
- [`search`](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.1/developer/03_modules_2.html#openerp.osv.orm.BaseModel.search), [`read`](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.1/developer/03_modules_2.html#openerp.osv.orm.BaseModel.read), [`write`](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.1/developer/03_modules_2.html#openerp.osv.orm.BaseModel.write) and [`create`](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.1/developer/03_modules_2.html#openerp.osv.orm.BaseModel.create) are called by the client in order to access and update record data, and should gracefully accept or return values for the columns that were defined in the result of `fields_get`

By overriding properly these methods, you can completely implement dynamic columns, but you will need to preserve the API behavior, and handle the persistence of the data (if any) yourself, in real static columns or in other models.

There are a few examples of such dynamic columns sets in the official addons, for example in the `survey` module that needs to simulate survey forms based on the definition of the survey campaign.

<sup>1</sup> The `init()` method is only called when the model's module is installed or updated, in order to setup/update the database backend for this model. It relies on the `_columns` to do this.

Comment: Thanks Oliver. I got it. Actually, it was acceptable to set _columns from the __init__() function, because I just wanted to add one column field per internal Location in the database (which is fairly statical and I guess we'll just have to update the module if a new Location is created). My first approach was to create these fields from within init() function by code (invoking objects 'ir.model.fields' and 'ir.model.data'), but somehow they would not be recognized in the view (after adding the same fields through fields_view_get() of course). So I went with this approach and it is ok now.

Answer (score 2):

When you write `_columns = _get_dyna_cols()` in the class body, that function call is made right there, in the class body, as Python is still parsing the class itself. At that point, your `_get_dyn_cols` method is just a function object in the local (class body) namespace - and it is called.

The error message you get is due to the missing `self` parameter, which is inserted only when you access your function as a method - but this error message is not what is wrong here: what is wrong is that you are making an imediate function call and expecting an special behavior, like late execution.

The way in Python to achieve what you want - i.e. to have the method called authomatically when the attribute `colluns` is accessed is to use the "property" built-in.
In this case, do just this: `_columns = property(_get_dyna_cols)` - 
This will create a class attribute named "columns" which through a mechanism called "descriptor protocol" will call the desired method whenever the attribute is accessed from an instance.

To leran more about the property builtin, check the docs: http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property

Comment: Not sure your solution will work for him, given the OpenERP framework, but your analysis of the problem is spot-on.

Comment: Hi nicobustillos , can u please clarify the successful answer because I m too stuck while creating dynamic fields. I have used Alter command within my function to create the field in db .